# Alert not showing after clicking link

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created a Buy Now link that pulls the URL from my phpmyadmin database. Clicking the link adds the product to the cart but I would not like the user to go to checkout when they click the link, but instead stay on the same page and pop an alert saying 'Product was added to cart'. Below is my current script but the alert does not show up and the user goes to the link. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thanks!

```
<script>
    $("#shop").onclick(function(event){
        $.post( '" . $producturl[0]->URL . "' );
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Added To Cart');
    });
</script>


<?php $producturl = ProductURL::find(array('Product'=>$tube1->Tube1));
    if($producturl[0]->URL!=NULL){
        echo '<a href="' . $producturl[0]->URL . '" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-theme="d" target="vspage" onclick="' . "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Buy Now', 'Tube', '" . $tube1->Tube1 . "'" . "]); _gaq.push(['_link', '" . $producturl[0]->URL . "']);" . '" id="shop">Test Cart</a>';

        echo '<a href="#" id="shop">Test2 Cart</a>';
    }
?>
```

$producturl[0]->URL is the array that pulls the current product to cart from phpmyadmin

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: I'd prefer using `$('.lnk').on('click', function() { /* do sth */ });`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed my code to this and the alert now pops up but the cart doesn't update. Any ideas? 

http://paste.ofcode.org/nzRxWq8bKpEfhbjWKyFQuf

Comment: It should be `$.post( '<?php echo $producturl[0]->URL; ?>' );` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774586/cart-not-being-updated-after-clicking-link-through-js#comment45827482_28774586

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the anchor so your text is no longer a link, then make it a span with the `shop` id:

```
<?php $producturl = ProductURL::find(array('Product'=>$tube1->Tube1));

        if($producturl[0]->URL!=NULL){
            echo '<span id="shop">Test Cart</span>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Hello, I removed the anchor and it works with the span. The alert pops up but my cart doesn't get updated when clicked.

I currently have: 
    $.post( '" . $producturl[0]->URL . "' );

to send this URL over (which is the add to cart link) -- is this not the correct method?

Comment: Ahh, I pulled the `onclick="' . "_gaq.push...` out of your `<a href=...>` code.  You will have to tuck that all back into the `$("#shop").onclick(function(event){` function.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: This is my current code with the span but the cart does not update. Can you by chance take a look? 

http://paste.ofcode.org/nzRxWq8bKpEfhbjWKyFQuf

Comment: @chronotrigga: Has anyone told you about your strange use of double/single quotes  :-)  [Try this](http://paste.ofcode.org/3WrZ4upC5wstp9PmVnQd44) - I changed the anchor to a span and deleted everything in the tag before the `onclick` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.alert('Added To Cart')
```

instead of

```
console.log('Added To Cart')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have jQuery and change to:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#shop").click(function(event){ 

          event.preventDefault();

          // Your code here

          // Alert user
          alert('Added To Cart'); 

       });
   });
```

And you should have only one unique id on same page! You have two `shop` ids.

**Update:**

You have this too:

`$.post( '" . $producturl[0]->URL . "' );`

To use php variables in javascript you should echo them, like:

```
$.post( '<?php echo $producturl[0]->URL;?>' );
```

I don't know what that `$producturl[0]->URL` variable have it, but this is not enought to update your cart, maybe you don't need this `$.post` to if you don't want to make anything from server side right now... perhaps you just want to update customer cart, like total price, quantity, add the new product...

But if you really need to do something from server side at this moment, check `$.post` documentation [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is $(document).on('click', '#shop', function (event) { pretty much the same function as .click? 

The alert pops up now but doesn't register into my cart with my $.post function shown here: http://paste.ofcode.org/nzRxWq8bKpEfhbjWKyFQuf

Comment: I'm currently using WooCommerce so $producturl[0]->URL is the URL table in phpmyadmin that links to the product being added to the cart. ie: http://shop.com/cart/?add-to-cart=1126

I have them in a mysql database because I have multiple products so I used the array

Comment: Is $.post the right method to use to send the URL over so the cart can recognize it is adding the product from the link?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not inside WooCommerce, but I don't think its enough, since from your example product id is sent by url (`$_GET`) not from `$_POST`.
`$.post` is used, for example, to send some information to some php script that will make something on the server side, but this will not change anything in real time, that you will magicly saw the cart being updated...you need to do some other things. Maybe there's some method/function from the core of WooCommerce, but I don't use it...try to make another question since this one is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $producturl = ProductURL::find(array('Product'=>$tube1->Tube1));
    if($producturl[0]->URL!=NULL){      
echo '<a href="#shop" id="shop">Test2 Cart</a>';
}
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#shop', function (event) {
$.post( '" . $producturl[0]->URL . "' );
event.stopPropogation();
event.preventDefault();
alert('Product has been added to cart');
});
</script>
```

This is my current code now where the alert finally pops up but the cart itself when I go to the page does not update. I used `$.post`, any help for this last step woud be great!

Comment: There's an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28770099/edit) link below your question. Use that to edit the code into your _question_, don't post it as an answer.